# How can I restrict Contacts that are pulled into DocuSign for Salesforce based on Contact Role?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am trying to create a custom button on the Opportunity object which will pull Contacts which have a Contact Role of "Designated Contract Recipient" into the DocuSign for Salesforce interface. I have so far been unable to restrict it to just the contacts with this Role.

Our Salesforce instance is using DocuSign for Salesforce version 7.0.5. From searching online, I believe I need to use the following parameters:

CCRM - Maps a Salesforce Contact Role with a DocuSign Role (I have ensured that the DocuSign role has been set up in DocuSign for Salesforce settings)
CCTM - Maps a Salesforce Contact Role with a DocuSign Type
CRL - Using the LoadDefaultContacts~0 option stops DocuSign from pulling all Contacts related to the Opportunity.

```
{!URLFOR('/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope', null, [ 
SourceID = Opportunity.Id, 
CCRM = 'Designated Contract Recipient~Designated Contract Recipient', 
CCTM = 'Designated Contract Recipient~Signer', 
DST = '15b7259d-983b-434b-bd86-b271e79c5ba1', 
LA = '1', 
LF = '1', 
CRL = 'LoadDefaultContacts~0', 
CES = 'CPANA DocuSign Contract ready for Signature: ' + Opportunity.Name 
] 
)}
```

I would expect using the above code would only pull Contacts linked to the Opportunity which have "Designated Contract Recipient" listed as a Contact Role. However, this will not pull any Contacts into the DFS interface. If I switch the CRL LoadDefaultContacts parameter to 1, then it pulls all Contacts linked to the Opportunity (and correctly maps the Designated Contract Recipient to the appropriate signing tags in the template).